# SVG output of ImageMagick appears malformed

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick

I have a php script that generates icons, and returns them in a variety of formats, using ImageMagick. The bitmap formats like JPG, PNG, and even ICO work like a charm, but the SVG output does some weird things. Here is a minimal script to illustrate te case:

```php
<?php

$format = 'jpg';

$im = new Imagick;
$im->newImage(300, 300, new ImagickPixel('#ffffff'));
$im->setImageFormat($format);

$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setStrokeWidth(0);
$draw->setFillColor(new ImagickPixel('#ff0000'));
$draw->setFillOpacity(.5);
$draw->rectangle(50, 50, 249, 249);

$im->drawImage($draw);

header('Content-Type: ' . $im->getImageMimeType());

echo $im->getImageBlob();
```

Sample output:

[image: Pink square on white canvas.]

If I change the value of `$format` to `png` or `ico`, the image still works fine, and gets send with the proper MIME type header. When I switch the format to `svg`, the correct MIME type header is sent, and it does return *some* sort of SVG, but it appears to be malformed. This is the output of the sample script above:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg width="300" height="300">
stroke-width:0;fill:#FFFF00000000;fill-opacity:0.5;  <rect x="50" y="50" width="199" height="199"/>
</svg>
```

Notably, the `xmlns` attribute on the `svg` element is missing. Perhaps weirder, the rectangle attributes are not actually applied to the rectangle, but dumped as some sort of inline CSS (without the proper context for it to act as such).

Output that would work (and that I sort of expected) would be:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="300" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect x="50" y="50" width="199" height="199" stroke-width="0" fill="#FF0000" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
</svg>
```

Also, a `viewBox` property with the correct dimensions would be nice, but that is not a deal-breaker.

Am I missing something? Perhaps some operation that needs to be applied before rendering as a vector format? Maybe it’s a bug? I can’t find any information on it, and any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

### Update 2019-11-25

Plot twist. I hadn’t noticed this before, but when I omit the `drawImage` step in my example, I get different output altogether:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">  <image id="image0" width="300" height="300" x="0" y="0"
    xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAAEsAQAAAABRBrPYAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJN
AAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAAAmJLR0QAAd2KE6QAAAA+SURB
VGje7coxAQAACAOg9U9rA1dBf7jJXkw0TdM0TdM0TdM0TdM0TdM0TdM0TdM0TdM0TdM0TdM0TdO0
fytHkUx5BCDW7AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />
</svg>
```

It now creates a PNG background image that it parses inline for some reason, but it also introduces aspects that were missing before; notably `xmlns` and `viewBox`.

The whole markup looks the same as something that *Inkscape* would produce. Which probably makes sense, as I read somewhere that this is one of the libraries that *ImageMagick* can use to render SVGs.

It’s almost as if the `drawImage` method breaks the *Inkscape* parser, and it falls back to some inferior engine or something. I hope this narrows the path to a solution.

Comment: Do you have `libmagickcore6-extra` installed? I assume so because it gets this far, but maybe it's an older version with less support?

Comment: Honestly I don’t know, @JeremyHarris. Im currently running this script on a Windows machine (yeah, I know). php says the `imagick module version` is `3.4.4RC2`, and that `Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version` has the value `ImageMagick 7.0.7-11 Q16 x64 2017-11-23 http://www.imagemagick.org`. That is pretty much it. Is `libmagickcore6-extra` something I could have php include?

Comment: My understanding is that library adds the SVG support. Perhaps make a docker container and run linux with the `libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra` package?

Comment: I hope to find a solution for within this development environment, because this is a part of a much larger application, but I will definitely look into it. Thanks, @JeremyHarris.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: No problem, @JeremyHarris. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: This question should have a higher bounty. Since SVG is technically a markup language, solving this problem would require a *better* translation algorithm from a raster image to vector. 50 points seems kinda ... low?

Comment: @GetSet, I’m not asking for someone to write me a better library. I’m merely asking if I’m missing something in my current approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [ImageMagic](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=31503) board, export to SVG is rather problematic as the library is intended for raster images, not vector graphics. From what I understand SVG output will always be an image tag with base64 encoded binary data. The workaround for your requirement might look like this:

```
$im = new Imagick;
$im->newImage(300, 300, new ImagickPixel('#ffffff'));
$im->setImageFormat('svg');

$im1 = new Imagick();
$im1->newImage(300, 300, new ImagickPixel('#ffffff'));
$im1->setImageFormat('png');
$fillColor = new ImagickPixel('#ff0000');
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFillColor($fillColor);
$draw->setStrokeWidth(0);
$draw->setFillOpacity(.5);
$draw->rectangle(50, 50, 249, 249);
$im1->drawImage($draw);

$im->compositeImage($im1->getimage(), Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPY, 0, 0);

header('Content-Type: image/svg+xml');

echo $im->getImageBlob();
```

Comment: Thanks. I was under the impression _ImageMagick_ could output SVG. Though this appears to be technically correct, the way it does it isn’t particularly useful. I guess I’ll go back to an ol’ switch inside my software that triggers completely different logic based on the requested MIME type, like I was doing all along. Not what I was hoping for, but your answer is clear and the bounty is yours.